# servlet context not only only for servlets. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Can I have an object in the spring application context which i can dynamically set and delete like the attributes in the servlet context and to be available for the whole app not only from servlet. I will set it on server start and then every x hours will bi changed with quarts. I know about the beans but it seems to be an overkill because i have to create them and put them in the config. I just want servlet context but not only for servlets because i want to save quarts generated values in it.

Comment: A singleton bean? What do you mean by "I know about the beans but it seems to be an overkill because i have to create them and put them in the config"? Do you mean that you find it overkill to use spring beans? If so, why are you using spring in the first place? And what is overkill about it?

Comment: Just setup a `ConcurrentHashMap` instance as a singleton bean (return a Map from a `@Bean` annotated method). Inject it where you need it. Done.